# Is there any edition of AJAX toolkit for vs2017?

Tags: ajax, visual-studio

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2017, However, when I tried to install AJAX control toolkit, downloaded in Devexpress, it failed.

I wonder is there any edition of AJAX for vs2017?

[image]

Comment: Version 17 does support Visual Studio 2017. A quick Google Search told me that.

Comment: same issue with my VS 207 professional

Comment: So my solution is to install an old version of AJAX toolkit, which is 3.5.7.0123. This version was installed will dll file. Thank you guys!